# Syntax error when trying to use with_items inside of lineinfile

Tags: ansible

When I try to run this code, I get an error that says

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, hostfile.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 12, column 28

             line='someline1'
             with_items:
```

Is this an error with my indentations?  I have tried adjusting them to see if they were right, and all of the variations that I came up with resulted in the same error.

```
  1 - hosts: webservers
  2   remote_user: me
  3   become: yes
  4   become_method: sudo
  5   tasks:
  6
  7   - name: Set some kernel parameters
  8     lineinfile:  dest= /etc/hosts
  9                  state= present
 10                  insertafter= EOF
 11                  line= 'someline1'
 12                  with_items:
 13                    - { line: 'someline2' }
 14                    - { line: 'someline3' }
 15                    - { line: 'someline4' }
```

Is it an issue with the -'s on the line statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with_items, is not part of lininfile module, put this at the same level on the task. Yes identation, issue.

```
 hosts: webservers
 remote_user: me
 become: yes
 become_method: sudo
 tasks:
   - name: Set some kernel parameters
     lineinfile:  dest= /etc/hosts
                  state= present
                  insertafter= EOF
                  line= '{{ item }}'
     with_items:
       -someline2 
       -someline3 
       -someline4
```